# Call to undefined function curl_init() php 5.6.7 without wamp

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

**note: I am not using wamp or xampp**

My system Windows 8 on azure vm

php-5.6.7-Win32-VC11-x32

Apache 2.4.12-win32-VC11

I did uncomment "extension=php_curl.dll" but still i am getting this error--->Call to undefined function curl_init()

To solve this issue I did alot of googling and also stackoverflow (obviously)
but I couldn't for any result that could help

php.ini

```
extension=php_bz2.dll    
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.

; On windows:

extension_dir = "c:/php/ext/"

**apache error log**

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:13.407838 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3592:tid 560] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:13.407838 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3592:tid 560] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) PHP/5.6.7 OpenSSL/1.0.1l configured -- resuming normal operations

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:13.407838 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3592:tid 560] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:13.407838 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3592:tid 560] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:13.407838 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3592:tid 560] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1620

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:14.814069 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1620:tid 500] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Mon Apr 06 13:51:14.814069 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1620:tid 500] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

is there anything am I missing,thanks for your time and also i am sure this is not a duplicate question, because i did lot of search before posting this question

Comment: restarted apache after editing config file?

Comment: @Hett  hahaha.....sorry i forgot to mention that I restarted my server after editing php.ini :)